# Send bulk emails in Apache Camel without closing connection

Tags: java, spring, email, apache-camel

Does [Apache Camel Mail Component](http://camel.apache.org/mail.html) support reuse of TCP connection for sending bulk emails?

If not, is it feasible/recommendable to write custom [org.apache.camel.component.mail.JavaMailSender](http://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.9.0/camel-mail/apidocs/org/apache/camel/component/mail/JavaMailSender.html) to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not possible with the standard camel mail component and also implementing a JavaMailSender won't do the trick for you imo.

If you have a look at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailProducer(2.13.0):

```
public void process(final Exchange exchange) {
try {
    MimeMessage mimeMessage;

    final Object body = exchange.getIn().getBody();
    if (body instanceof MimeMessage) {
        // Body is directly a MimeMessage
        mimeMessage = (MimeMessage) body;
    } else {
        // Create a message with exchange data
        mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(sender.getSession());
        getEndpoint().getBinding().populateMailMessage(getEndpoint(), mimeMessage, exchange);
    }
    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOG.debug("Sending MimeMessage: {}", MailUtils.dumpMessage(mimeMessage));
    }
    sender.send(mimeMessage);
    // set the message ID for further processing
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(MailConstants.MAIL_MESSAGE_ID, mimeMessage.getMessageID());
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    exchange.setException(e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    exchange.setException(e);
}
}
```

There is only 1 message or exchange object send/handled. 
So maybe implementing your own "BulkMailComponent" with the functionality you need can be a solution for you.